# Can't get a decimal when multiplying a number by an integer from input

Tags: python

My goal is to fold a paper a certain number of times. For some reason it won't give me the thickness in decimals, but only as a whole number.

```
folds=input ("Choose how many times to fold the paper: ")

width=0.005

nWidth=width*folds

print ("The thickness after %d folds will be %d cm") %(folds, nWidth)
```

When I enter 200 it will print 1, but any number under 200 will print a 0. I've tried using float on nWidth and the input, but that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Edit: solved thanks to Ashwini. Changed the second %d to %f to get the float number.

Comment: Use `%f` for floats.

Comment: Thank you Ashwini! That worked out.

Comment: In python 2.6+, you can also use the new style format specification and let it automatically determine the output format based on type: `print "The thickness after {0} folds will be {1} cm".format(folds, nWidth)`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use new `.format()` method fo templating. It's more easy and powerful. You don't have to worry about types with it (truly duck typing).

```
print ("The thickness after {} folds will be {} cm".format(folds, nWidth))
```

More info: [Format examples](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-examples)

Comment: @Tom Eldar: You should really consider using this. The new format specification is a lot more powerful and intuitive (at least for me ;) ). +1